# TFLite: `ValueError: Model input is not quantized.`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

**Problem**

I try to convert the [`crop_and_resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize) operation to TFLite. I am using the script below. But the conversion fails and the error `ValueError: Model input is not quantized.` is raised.
Does someone have any idea? I did not find any relevant information on the related previous questions.

**Code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf

IMG_SIZE = 128
NUM_BOXES = 100
CROP_SIZE = 28
NB_DATA_SAMPLES = 32
BATCH_SIZE = 1


def create_model():
    images_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.float32)
    boxes_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=(NUM_BOXES, 4), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.float32)

    box_indices = tf.reshape(
        tf.repeat(
            tf.expand_dims(tf.range(BATCH_SIZE, dtype=tf.int32), axis=-1),
            NUM_BOXES,
            axis=-1
        ),
        shape=(-1,)
    )

    cropped_images = tf.image.crop_and_resize(
        image=images_,
        boxes=tf.reshape(boxes_, (-1, 4)),
        box_indices=box_indices,
        crop_size=(CROP_SIZE, CROP_SIZE))

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[images_, boxes_], outputs=cropped_images)
    model.summary(line_length=200)
    return model


model = create_model()

def representative_dataset_generator():
    for _ in range(NB_DATA_SAMPLES):
        image_ = tf.random.normal(shape=(1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
        bboxes_ = tf.random.uniform((1, NUM_BOXES, 4), maxval=1)
        yield [image_, bboxes_]

# Converter
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.int8]

converter.inference_input_type = tf.uint8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.uint8

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_generator
quant_model = converter.convert()
```

Thanks

Comment: I think ``crop_and_resize`` is not supported by tflite yet. https://www.tensorflow.org/mlir/tfl_ops#operation_definition

Comment: There is no TFL implementation so it falls back on a TFliteFlexDelegate but it can be converted :/

Comment: Hi! I am able to convert the model to Tflite in 2.6 , Attaching Gist for reference.   https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/76f2208c9e92edca3098d4bf6314d7c0/stack_67975382.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

I could execute your code successfully. However, it only quantize the Reshape layer but not crop layer. So I guess maybe tflite can't quantize the op they do not support.